# Updating a row item in knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm quite new to knockoutjs.

My question is how do I update an item in observable array when posting the item with a ajax post serverside in asp.net MVC.

Some of the values are recalculated on server-side only.

Do I need to return a new list or does I only need to return the updated item from server side.

And how does does knockout know which item to change.
I've searched Google without any luck.

Any help would appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you will need to send the updated values back to the client, or retrieve them from the server. you need to post some code of what you've tried so far. Asking a 'give me the code' type question won't get you very far on SO I'm afraid

Comment: Lets say I have "var updatedItem" back from ajax, how does I pass this to knoukout, there is not an update call. I will start coding later on and pass some code.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/657981/ASP-NET-MVC-with-Knockout-Js

Comment: Yes, you'd need to return a new list and update the observable array

Answer (score 0):

You need to move corresponding result of server request to bind observable Array.

Example: viewModel reference is consider it as self.

`self.tableData = ko.observableArray([{id: 1, name: 'XYZ' , score: 90},
                                     {id: 2, name: 'XZZ' , score: 80}

]);`

tableData is binded to html table.

Now you raise the ajax request. Then you get the response in success callback. 
consider as result in result.TABLEDATA = [{id: 3, name: 'QUS' , score: 60},
                                     {id: 4, name: 'YYY' , score: 70}];

now we need to move this data to our `self.tableData(result.TABLEDATA)`;

I Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi, I can explain clearly if you provide more details. Where you are binding  this array. If it is html table no need to update , it will automatically reflect. If it is kendo grid, then you need to refresh grid.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the values in the updated item are observable or not. If the array contains plain JavaScript objects, Knockout can't detect changes to them.

If the item in the array has observables, it can.

This example demonstrates this: http://jsfiddle.net/Quango/27tfmp0o/

```
self.Items = ko.observableArray([
    { Name: "Plain object", ID: 1},
    { Name: ko.observable("Knockout object"),
     ID: ko.observable(2)
    }
    ]);
```

The first item is a plain object. Clicking 'Change 1st' button changes the object, but nothing appears on screen. The second has observable values, so clicking 'Change 2nd' does update the item.

If you don't want to use observables, your best option is to remove the item from the array, change it, and then re-add it - demonstrated by clicking 'Replace 1st'